# Creating Pre-Populated Email link from Pdf

Tags: email, hyperlink

I am posting this here because I cannot find ANY help online with this specific issue.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

In Adobe InDesign, I've created an ebook which I've exported as an interactive pdf. On the last page are share links. I cannot find out how to create a pre-populated email link that would open an email client with a blank "To" field, a subject line and simple body text which includes a link.

There's tons of explanations on how to do this with html, but I'm not creating html pages. I'm creating an interactive pdf.

Any suggestions?
B.

BTW: I've posted on Adobe forums with no response.

Answer (score 0):

Use a button with a `gotoUrl` behaviour and type in:

```
mailto:name@company.com?subject=mySubjects&body=myTexte
```